# Failed to load sql modules into the database cluster during PostgreSQL Installation

Tags: postgresql, windows

I have attempted to install PostgreSQL 9.4 and 8.4 multiple times and it is failing no matter what I have tried. I am attempting to install on Windows 7 SP1 x64.  After each failed install I have uninstalled and deleted the installation folder to start fresh.

Each time I attempt the install I get an error pop up near the end of installation that says: 
*"failed to load sql modules into the database cluster".*

Then another error pop up displays immediately after that says:
*"Error running post install step.  Installation may not complete correctly. Error reading C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/postgresql.conf"*

I have attempted installation with the following actions:

- Always installed as administrator
- Turned off all virus protection and windows firewall
- Changed the installation directory to something other than the Program Files directory.
- Changed the data directory to something other than the installation directory of postgres

None of the actions above have helped and I always receive the error. Any help that someone can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please, per the Windows installation troubleshooting guide, get your installer log and post it here or upload it somewhere and link to it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Troubleshooting_Installation

Comment: I am having the same problem on Windows 10 Pro x64 when trying to install PostgreSQL 9.4.4 x64.  I installed VS 2015 Enterprise first; could the version of .Net framework have something to do with it?  Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: @CraigRinger For me, the error in the installer log is: `[20:49:14] Installing the adminpack module in the postgres database...
Executing C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4\bin\psql.exe -c "CREATE EXTENSION adminpack" -d postgres
Script exit code: 2

Script output:
 

Script stderr:
 psql: could not connwind
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Failed to load SQL modules into the database cluster.`

Comment: @CraigRinger When I ran the installer after disabling both Windows Defender and Windows Firewall, I received the same error message, but the installer also tried the IPv6 version of localhost (::1) before trying IPv4 localhost (127.0.0.1).  Otherwise, the two error messages were identical.

Comment: @JeffG Sounds like the server didn't start correctly after install and initdb. Check the server logs in the %PROGRAMFILES%\PostgreSQL\9.4\data\pg_log directory.

Comment: @CraigRinger After the install is completed, my data directory contains a single directory called pg_log (no other files or folders).  The pg_log directory is empty.  I should also add that the error I indicated is only the first error.  There is another that says `[17:40:25] Write ServiceID(postgresql-x64-9.4) to registry/ini...
Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly
 Error reading file D:/PostgreSQL/Data/postgresql.conf`

Comment: One other note: I cleanly installed Windows 10 twice.  On the first attempt, Postgres installed without issue.  On the second, the install is failing.  I don't have additional information for you on what exactly changed, but I know the order of installed software changed, which may be related.  The only difference that I noticed was that the first time, some .Net component was installed, and it wasn't done the second time.  That makes me think that perhaps VS2015 Enterprise (or some other application) installed an incompatible version of the .Net framework, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Before you try anything drastic like long command lines and making new user accounts, try using a password during the installer that only consists of alpha-numeric characters. I don't know why quote characters and other punctuation marks cause a problem but they do.

Comment: Before You anything do, pls check next symbols in admin password: % < >
My answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48511456/2995126

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was getting this same error when trying to install PostgreSQL v9.4.4 on Windows 10 Pro.  Starting with [a solution hosted on Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10241/postgresql-the-database-cluster-initialization-failed), I came up with the following steps that allowed the installer to run successfully:

> 1) Create a new user account, called *postgres*
>   2) Add the new account to the *Administrators* and *Power Users* groups
>   3) Restart the computer
>       NOTE: I added step #3, since step #4 didn't work without it
>   4) Run a command prompt as the postgres user, using the command:
>       *runas /user:postgres cmd.exe*
>   5) Run the installer from the *postgres* command window
>   6) Delete the *postgres* user account, as well as the user directory
>       NOTE: I added step #6, since the postgres account is not required after installation

Comment: NOTE: I only ran into this issue because I followed the instructions to [change the location of the Users directory on Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1964-users-folder-move-location-windows-10-a.html).  After many attempts at setting this up, I came to the conclusion that it messes up enough installers (Microsoft's Web Installer, .NET 3.5, Azure SDK, Postgres, others) that it wasn't worth it.  When I installed Windows 10 normally, I had no issues.

Comment: I am not sure if it was because I just installed Windows 10 or because I followed your instructions but I got the install to work finally.  Thanks!

Comment: Wow... Having no idea why PostgreSQL not setting this 6-steps in their installation package. Worked for me on `Windows 7` and `postgresql-9.5.1-1-windows-x64`

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 8 without adding the _postgres_ user to the _Power Users_ group (which didn't exist).

Comment: Easiest way of adding a local user on Windows 10: Start -> run -> `control userpasswords2` (taken from http://www.groovypost.com/howto/create-local-account-windows-10/)

Comment: Fixed my issue. Follow steps described in: https://community.thingworx.com/community/developers/blog/2017/07/25/resolving-failed-to-load-sql-modules-into-database-cluster-issue-when-installing-postgresql-windows

Comment: Not the answer for Windows 8.1.  Get the same error following these steps.  Note: I am using Data location in a user's directory.  Will try a different location outside of the user's directory and comment on one of those answers.

Comment: Thank you! This is the only thing that worked for me after trying several other solutions - I'm on Windows 10 with PostgreSQL 10.1

Comment: `net user postgres /add` - `net user postgres password` - `net localgroup administrators postgres /add` - `net localgroup "Power Users" postgres /add` - `runas /user:postgres "C:\path\to\postgres\installer.exe"` - `password` - `net user postgres /delete` - `RMDIR /S /Q C:\Users\postgres` ... Those commands will do everything above, without reboots.

Answer (score 45):

Encountered a very similar problem that OP is reporting today while installing Postgres 9.4.

It turns out that the password generator I was using has made a password that contains non-alphanumeric characters. ("^") I believe was the culprit in this case. Removing that allowed the installation of Postgres 9.4 (Windows 64 bit) to complete.

Very easy fix once you've found it, but the error message that comes up is not descriptive, so in this case I didn't notice at first what I was doing wrong.

Comment: This was what fixed my problem too, agreed very very vague error message.

Comment: This was the solution to my problem where I received the exact error message in the question. I received the error message on Windows Server 2016 Standard x64 using Postgres 11.1.1 x64. Once I removed the special characters from password I was able to install Postgres 11.1.1 x64 without the error.

Comment: Up, up, up. Nothing else helped me, but this finally solved my issue. This shouldn't be buried.

Comment: Yes, this fixed my problem.  It's terrible that the installer doesn't even tell you what characters are valid and if you entered invalid characters.

Comment: Had the same issue on a Windows Server2012 R2, this fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Same problem here. I had a backslash \ at the end of the password.

From the install log `%temp%\install-postgresql.log` it seems to be a quoting/escaping bug in the EDB Windows Installer which calls `cscript initcluster.vbs` with the password as command line argument.

Comment: Fixed it for me. Using KeePassXC. I unchecked the non-alphanumeric character option, updated the password & the Postgres installer worked great. Windows 10 + Postgres 13.

Comment: one would think they'd add a paragraph about this when making said pw

Comment: In my case this was it. I did as password "" (two double quotes) and it would fail. Thanks. Saved me hours here

Comment: This worked for me. My password had quote characters. Try a different password before the other really complicated answers on this page. Is there a way to raise this answer above the accepted one?

Comment: This fixed my problem. I have tried finding any trace of an "Allowed characters" list for the passwords in postgres, but I can't find anything official from EDB. They really should provide that list, and implement checks in their installer window. I don't dare to think about how many hours are wasted every year due to troubleshooting this, it's such a waste and a shame.

Answer (score 15):

What worked for me is, during the install, specifying a Postgre SQL data folder that's outside of any Windows user profile directory (C:\Users), such as C:\postgres-data.

My setup:

- Win 10 Pro
- PostgreSQL 9.5 RC1

I ran into this issue when I tried setting PostgreSQL's data directory somewhere under my user profile's directory, such us somewhere under "My Documents".

I tried Jeff G's solution and it didn't work at first. It worked only when I kept the data directory as the default (C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data). So then I tested further and tried setting the data directory to somewhere outside of any user profile directories (i.e. somewhere that isn't under C:\Users). For example, C:\postgres-data and this worked.

I then just tried using that directory with my default user, and not bothering with the postgres temp user as outlined in Jeff G's solution and that also worked. So in the end, it had to do with my data directory being somewhere under C:\Users. As long as it was outside of that, it worked.

Answer (score 10):

None of these answers here helped me, finally I solved this problem by creating the folder before the installation (C:\PostgreSQL\data) and giving it full access for the group "Users".

Windows 7 x64, postgresql-9.5.2-1-windows-x64

Comment: None of the other answers helped me either, so I did similar to this and it worked for me.

Comment: Coming here in 2023. Deleting the data folder worked for me on mac.
chown -R <username>: /Library/PostgreSQL
rm -R  /Library/PostgreSQL

Answer (score 6):

When installing PostgreSQL, do not use the following symbols in your database's admin password: `%`, `<`, and `>`.

[Bug report and problem solution here](http://www.postgresql-archive.org/BUG-14846-Failed-to-load-SQL-modules-into-the-database-cluster-td5987134.html)

Comment: Please write your answer in English, since [Stack Overflow is an English site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)

Comment: Now this post is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: @FrankerZ This isn't borderline link-only

Comment: @Rob Agree to disagree.

Comment: When I ran the installation (after a failed attempt), I tried changing the default directories and that didn't work; the setup wizard returned the same error. I really didn't want to create a new security user so I decided to try a different password (without the characters you mentioned) and it turns out this was the issue.Thanks for sharing your solution.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped someone

Comment: The quotation mark ( " ) may also not be part of the password... :-/

Answer (score 6):

Hope It's Work.

1.)Uninstall PostgreSQL

2.)Delete the postgres user if it still exists :

> net user postgres /delete

3.) Create the postgres user with a password you can remember:

> net user /add postgres

4.) Add the postgres user to the Administrators group:

> net localgroup administrators postgres /add

5.) Add the postgres user to the Power Users group

> net localgroup "power users" postgres /add

6.) Run a command window as the postgres user:

> runas /user:postgres cmd.exe

7.) Change user postgres and install postgresql

8.)Back your and remove the postgres user from the Administrators group.

> net localgroup administrators postgres /delete

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error ("Failed to load SQL modules into the database cluster.") when installing on W2K12R2 using the EnterpriseDB installer linked to from the PostgreSQL [Windows download page](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/). I tried running the installer with admin privs, and using the postgres-user solution offered by Jeff G, but neither worked. Finally I tried the second installer, [BigSQL](http://www.bigsql.org/postgresql/installers.jsp), and that installed without issue.

Comment: thank you so much for this but has it occurred to you once you open the file and insert your password it does not work? Like once I press on PostgreSQL 10 in the Object browser I got an Error has occured connecting to the serve: FATAL role my username does not exist

Answer (score 3):

- Changed the data directory to something other than the installation directory of postgres

Make sure `NETWORK SERVICE` has read/write permissions on that folder, the installation was failing for me until I did this.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too with 9.5 and got around it by:

1. Installing with the default data folder.
2. Making sure my new data folder had full control access for the "NETWORK SERVICE" account.
3. Then changing the default PGDATA folder as per this instruction: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Change_the_default_PGDATA_directory_on_Windows

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and noticed that some Postgres .bat files were opening in a text editor. Text editors opening files during installation isn't too uncommon, but I noticed these batch files were setting directory permissions. I then found that .bat files were set to open in a text editor (Notepad++) by default. I changed the default program for .bat files, uninstalled Postgres, re-ran the installer, and it worked perfectly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before. I solved this by installing Visual Studio C++ Express first.

Comment: Could you please let me know, how does the installation of VS helps to solve the OP's problem? Really curious

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience as **@gomisha**. **@Jeff G**'s solution did not work for me no matter which user ran the installer.

As long as the target data directory was anywhere under `c:\users`, the install *or* database cluster init would fail.

I was successful after creating `c:\postgresql-data` and ensuring that the `postgres` user had `full access` in the 'effective access' tool.

*Note: I did not use `control userpasswords2` to set up the `postgres` user; I did it through the traditional crappy Windows 10 user wizard that tries to make the user sign up for hotmail.* I did run the install as `postgres`.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue with the BigSQL windows installer PostgreSQL-9.6.5-1-win64-bigsql.exe
The problem turned out to be that my system path was too long.  After removing some uncessary junk from my System Path, and then reinstalling, the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be better as individual comments above, but I don't have the required rep. I just spent days on this, with Postgres 10 on Win 10 Creators. My "answer" was to let Postgres put the data in its default install folder instead of my User folder (where it would be automatically backed-up).

**1. This problem can happen with no reported install errors at all.** On my very first try, I saw:

```
Failed to load SQL modules into the database cluster.
```

But that seemed to be due to:

```
Executing C:\Users\loren\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_aee8e5a76f\vcredist_x64.exe /passive /norestart
Script exit code: 3010

    MSI (s) (AC:FC) [14:21:35:341]: Product: Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86 Minimum Runtime - 12.0.40660. 
Restart required. The installation or update for the product required a restart for all changes to take effect.  
The restart was deferred to a later time.
```

Restarting Windows *after* the failure of the rest of the Postgres installation did not let Postgres run.

Once VC was in place, uninstalling and re-installing Postgres (still with its data in my User folder) completed with no reported errors. But every attempt to access it, by any means, still resulted in something like this:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin>psql
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The RawCap sniffer showed TCP SYN followed immediately by RST,ACK on localhost for both v4 and v6 for each try. Netstat did not see port 5432 in use at all. All Postgres runtime logs were totally empty. In Windows Services, I could manually start the postgresql-x64-10 service, but it immediately stopped itself, with the note that some services do that normally.

**2. I tried moving the data directory via the Postgres wiki procedure. Apparently for Postgres 10 it is incomplete.** It does not deal with:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-10\Data Directory
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Services\postgresql-x64-10\Data Directory
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\pg_env.bat
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\scripts\serverctl.vbs
```

But fixing every data file instance I could find did not let it run. And even after fixing all those, and uninstalling and re-installing again with the default location, the new pgAdmin4 somehow still remembered my original User data directory location!

**3. I did not try giving NETWORK SERVICE read/write permissions on my User folder.** Once the default install worked I wanted to get on with my original project...  Maybe that would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

One of the answers [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10241/postgresql-the-database-cluster-initialization-failed) is the only thing that worked on my machine:

> I had the same error message when trying to install 9.2.4. My issue
> was because even though the Win2k8 server had %SYSTEMROOT%\system32 as
> part of the path, no programs could "see" anything in
> C:\Windows\system32. The installer heavily uses icacls.exe during the
> init routine. Since my path was screwed up, the installer bombed out.
>
> Once I explicitly added C:\Windows\system32 to the SYSTEM's Path
> environment variable and re-ran the installer as an admin, everything
> worked fine.

Credits to the [user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/29298/mark).

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `services.msc`
2. Search for postgres service
3. Go to Log On tab
4. Select local account
5. Profit

Answer (score 0):

The alternative solution for problems with PostgreSQL installer is setting this up with a Docker.

1. Install Docker Desktop

   https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/
2. Start installed Docker Desktop
3. In PowerShell, run:

   docker pull postgres
4. In PowerShell, run:

   docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword postgres
5. Now you can connect to the Postgres server for example with pgAdmin on the same machine, using:

   - host: localhost
   - port: 5432
   - maintenance database: postgres
   - username: postgres
   - password: mypassword