# Install PostgreSQL data in user folder

Tags: windows, postgresql, service, installation

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL (version 9.4.5-2 x64) in my computer and I would like to put data in my user folder. I think that it is better to do not lose data when uninstall Postgre later or even format programs partition.

The problem is that it doesn't initiate the PostgreSQL service, even using Administrator profile. It shows a message saying: `Failed to load SQL Modules into the database cluster.`, probably because it couldn't initiate the service.

I tried many different folders and even changing some permissions it was not possible to do this. The best alternative was to put it on program data folder. Is there anything that I could do to put it or in local user app data or my documents folder?

Regards,
Leandro

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689251/failed-to-load-sql-modules-into-the-database-cluster-during-postgresql-installat/31815962#31815962)?

> 1) Create a new user account, called postgres
>
> 2) Add the new account to the Administrators and Power Users groups
>
> 3) Restart the computer
>
> 4) Run a command prompt as the postgres user, using the command:
>
> runas /user:postgres cmd.exe
>
> 5) Run the installer from the postgres command window
>
> 6) Delete the postgres user account, as well as the user directory

Comment: The `postgres` user should *not* be an Administrator.

Comment: This is an opition but it's not possible to use in Inno Setup (my idea) because it asks for postgres profile authentication.