# PostgreSQL reinstallation

Tags: windows, postgresql, installation

I was recently following this on stack overflow and have tried all mentioned solutions and still pull the same error.

[Failed to load sql modules into the database cluster during PostgreSQL Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689251/failed-to-load-sql-modules-into-the-database-cluster-during-postgresql-installat)

I have removed the keys deleted and uninstalled all things related to postgresql
however there is something occupying port 5432 which should be postgres. 
using netstat it looks like tomcat is using that port.
 previously I had pg using that port. 
So I proceeded with the installation on 5433 and 
I can open up pg admin but upon attempting to connect to the data base I get error server doesnt listen the server doesnt accept connections. I am using Windows 7 Professional

How do I completely remove postgres from my machine as if it never existed because the installation worked fine before I uninstalled and reinstalled. As I mentioned before I have tried all of the solutions in the link

Comment: Any chance of some actual information? Windows version, errors in the installation log, that sort of thing? Why do you think something is occupying 5432 and why can't you identify what it is?

Comment: @RichardHuxton I have added more detail do you know where I can find the installation log?? I looked in the folder containing postgres and could not find anything

Comment: The installer should say where the logs are on error. You should also figure out why tomcat is sitting on port 5432. Then,  check that the postgresql server is running on 5433 and then check that pgadmin is trying to connect to that port.

Comment: while using pgAdmin, your connection string is "localhost" or some sort of IP?