# PostgreSQL reinstall : Failed to load sql modules into the database cluster

Tags: postgresql

I tried to re-install postgresql 9.5.3-1 on my windows 7 without success. In fact, at each attempt, I have the message:

> failed to load sql modules into the database cluster

then, I get the message:

> Error running post install step. Installation may not complete correctly. Error reading C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/data/postgresql.conf

I tried several attempts to solve this issue

- change the installation folder
- switch to 32-bit
- reboot
- clean the register before reinstalling
- install as a postgres user as describe here ([Failed to load sql modules into the database cluster during PostgreSQL Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689251/failed-to-load-sql-modules-into-the-database-cluster-during-postgresql-installat))

PS: installation language is French

[image: Failed to load sql modules]

[image: Error reading]

Comment: You might want to take a look at the installation log or add it to your question. See paragraph 4.3 on the following page for instructions where to find the log https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Troubleshooting_Installation

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a solution to my problem. I just installed postgres as a super administrator

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem. Just double check permission for your data folder. I set full control to authenticated users and it installs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.

In my case it was a backslash `\` at the end of the password.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/32146553/2443630