# Issues while installing PostgreSQL in Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, windows-10

When I tried to install PostgreSQL on Windows 10 (64-bit), I was getting a prompt saying:

> 'Failed to load SQL modules into the database cluster'

and

> 'problem running post-install setup'.

Comment: Please provide some clarifications if you installled postgresql as administrator..

Answer (score 8):

Did you install postgresql with administrator-privileges?

This might be due to a privilege-issue, you can try to:

- Create a new user account, called *postgres*
- Add the new account to the *Administrators* and *Power Users* groups
- Restart the computer
- Run a command prompt as the *postgres* user, using the command:`runas /user:postgres cmd.exe`
- Run the installer from the *postgres* command window
- Delete the *postgres* user account, as well as the user directory

Another option is to:

1. Uninstall PostgreSQL
2. Delete the *postgres* user if it still exists.

   ```
    net user postgres /delete
   ```
3. Create the *postgres* user with a password

   ```
    net user /add postgres <password>
   ```
4. Add the *postgres* user to the Administrators group

   ```
    net localgroup administrators postgres /add
   ```

5a. Add the *postgres* user to the Power Users group

```
    net localgroup "power users" postgres /add
```

5b. Add the *postgres* user to the administrator's local-group

```
    net localgroup Administrators postgres /add
```

6. Run a command window as the *postgres* user

   ```
    runas /user:postgres cmd.exe
   ```
7. Run the install file from within the command window.

   ```
    C:\Download\postgresql-9.6.12-windows.exe // or whatever version you are using
   ```

   This should run the installation successfully.
8. Remove the *postgres* user from the Administrators group.

   ```
    net localgroup administrators postgres /delete
   ```

as mentioned by @Imraan on DBA -> [Link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10241/postgresql-the-database-cluster-initialization-failed/22149#22149)

Edit in regards to @Youssef's comment:

Depending on the version and scenario, the user `postgres` needs to be added to administrator's `localgroup` instead of `power users`.

Short overview about power-users from [superuser SE](https://superuser.com/questions/241092/difference-between-power-user-and-administrator):

> Note: in Windows 7 and above, Power Users only exists for legacy purposes, and is the same as ordinary Users, unless an admin explicitly adds extra rights to the group.

Power-users may:

- Run legacy applications, in addition to Windows 2000 or Windows XP Professional certified applications.
- Install programs that do not modify operating system files or install system services.
- Customize systemwide resources including printers, date, time, power options, and other Control Panel resources.
- Create and manage local user accounts and groups.
- Stop and start system services which are not started by default.
- Power Users do not have permission to add themselves to the Administrators group.
- Power Users do not have access to the data of other users on an NTFS volume, unless those users grant them permission.

Comment: I had to add postgres to administrators localgroup instead of power users

Answer (score 0):

As for me, all I had to do to was to run the installer as an administrator
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the previous answers did not help, check the password you insert. I had the same issue and, as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689251/failed-to-load-sql-modules-into-the-database-cluster-during-postgresql-installat), I just had to enter an alphanumeric password and I could finish the installation without further problems.